# Number and Types of States of Matter

Tags: condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate, matter, states-of-matter

I wanted to know if there were more than 5 states of matter (man-made or natural) and so I searched it up. Other than solid, liquid, gas, plasma, and Bose-Einstein state, these were varying results from 7 to 15 different states. I want to know what the real answer is. How many states are there and what are they? Also, what is a condensate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as we are lacking any fundamental physical definition to a "states of matter", we will have arbitrary amount of these states of matter. This is well discussed in this question;
[What determines a state of matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87488/what-determines-a-state-of-matter)

Condensate is practically a matter, where molecules holds their relative positions to each other in same order atleast over short period of time. Ie, kinetic gas theory doesn't apply.